# server policy problem: client gets "your credentials did not work" when connecting with saved password

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I connect to a production machine (Windows Server 2008) using Remote Desktop Connection (via mRemoteNG client) directly from my home computer. I would like my to save password, so that I don't have to type it each time.

Unfortunately, there are some policy restrictions, because when I connect with saved password I'm getting the following message:

"Your credentials did not work
The server's authentication policy does not allow connection requests using saved credentials. Please enter new credentials."

What exactly has to be configured on the server to allow me to keep the password saved on my machine?

Comment: Are you the user or admin? Also are you using domain\user or user@domain.local in the onnection also how do you connect to the server, vpn or.......

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration" --> Right click on "RDP-Tcp" Under "Connections" and go to Properties --> Go to the "Log on Settings" tab and uncheck "Always prompt for password"

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use saved credentials in this situation you need to do the following in your **Windows 7 machine**:

1. Open Group Policy Editor via **cmd -> gpedit.msc**
2. Navigate to **Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation**
3. Open Setting **Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication**, set it to **Enabled** click on button **Show...** and in **Show Contents** window add Value TERMSRV/***.**
4. Close all windows by pressing **OK**.
5. Run **cmd** and enter **gpupdate /force** command to update your policy.

Now you should be able to use your saved credentials.

**Note:**  Credentials are ONLY saved when a host or DNS name is supplied.  When it's an IP address it will never save the credentials.

References: [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/remote-desktop-connection-not-using-saved/13a17d84-b008-4767-95fb-b891e9e6bc66?auth=1)

If you don't want to change anything on local or server side, Do this:

1. Go to **Control Panel -> Credential Manager**. You will see three sections:
2. Add your credentials under **Generic Credentials**.

   Now you can RDP without entering password.

Answer can also be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/396722/your-system-administrator-does-not-allow-the-user-of-saved-credentials-to-log-on?rq=1) in the similar question.

Comment: Ya thanks for the guide, the first section helped to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The user, when logging in and getting this error message, can click Delete on the login window to remove and re-enter the credentials.

If you are a sysadmin and you have users with this issue, it is likely that the GPO was set that way intentionally, so don't just turn that security feature off.